# How to execute command prompt and get the output from it?

Tags: python, cmd

I am a newbie of Python and I would like to write a Python program that can execute some command in the cmd and get the output from it automatically.

Is it possible? How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean get input form the command line interactively ?

Comment: The question seems a little vague to me. Do you want to pass arguments through cmdline to get a result? Or is it just compiling the code "python blah.py"  for example?

Comment: I interpret this so that the op wants to call something from the command line. Like a subprocess.

Comment: Oh, I mean input text to the cmd and get the result from it

Comment: This might help: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html But I'm unsure of what you are asking so maybe not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> r = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-l']) #List files on a linux system. Equivalent of dir on windows.
>>> output, errs = r.communicate()
>>> print(output)
Total 72
# My file list here
```

The `Popen`-construtor accepts a list of arguments as the first parameter. The list starts with the command (in this case `ls`) and the rest of the values are switches and other parameters to the command. The above example is written as `ls -l` on the terminal (or command line, or console). A windows equivalent would be

```
>>> r = subprocess.Popen(['dir', '/A'])
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean how to excute some command from cmd
use

```
import os
```

os.system(a string);

Comment: Please avoid `os.system()`. It's deprecated and the official way is to use subprocess. It says this on the documentation of the function.